# Active link turn different color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to link those three scripts so that a active link turns to a different color purple. jquery.js contains the downloaded jquery library. I don't know why it is not working as expected. Anyone?

```
<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="color.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<div class="nav-container" >
<ul class="navigation-menu" >
  <li><a href='start.php'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='pay.php'>C2B Payments</a> </li>
  <li><a href='sms.php'>C2B SMS</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>B2C Payments</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="getbtc.php"> B2C Payments</a></li>
      <li><a href="payment.php"> Make Payments</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href='bsms.php'>B2C SMS</a></li>
  <li><a href='index.php'>Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
//JS color.js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});

 //css site.css
.navigation-menu li a.active {
  background-color: purple;
  color:#fff;
  }
```

Comment: its working already your code , wht do u expect  still the active link changed the background color ?

Comment: What is expected ?

Comment: The problem is that clicking a link causes the browser to load the specified page, replacing the current page in which you had applied the class change. (Your code would work if the links didn't load a new page: https://jsfiddle.net/wecttb36/.) You could add code to the ready handler to extract the name of the current page from `location.href` and then select the corresponding anchor to apply the class to.

Comment: becaz its href so i will do refresh

Comment: $(this).addClass("active").css({'background-color': purple;'color':'#fff'});

Comment: @nnnnnn so precisely how do I do that? It's new to me.

Comment: I added @ihemant360 `
 
$(this).addClass("active")` and it works ..but the links do not load

Comment: I don't know the structure of your URLs, but something like this in the ready handler could work: `$("a[href='" + location.href.match(/\/(\w+\.php)/)[1] + "']").addClass("active")`.

Comment: If page refreshes on link click - so no ajax - I think you don't need JS to style your links, just add `active` class from PHP :)

Comment: @nnnnnn you mean I should have this? `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("a[href='" + location.href.match(/\/(\w+\.php)/)[1] + "']").addClass("active")
});
});`

Comment: No, my suggestion should go directly in your ready handler, *not* within the click handler. (If it works - and again I was guessing at the strucdture of your URLs - you won't need the click handler.)

Comment: @nnnnnn would you mind showing me on [https://jsfiddle.net/wecttb36/] honestly am new to front end dev.

Comment: I've added an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navigation-menu" >
  <li class="active"><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>C2B Payments</a> </li>
  <li><a href='#'>C2B SMS</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>B2C Payments</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> B2C Payments</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Make Payments</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href='#'>B2C SMS</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.active{
  background-color:purple;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('li > a').click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('active').css("background-color", "");

   var $paren = $(this).parent();
        if (!$paren.hasClass('active')) {
            $paren.addClass('active');
        }
});
});
```

Comment: (Assuming you fix the syntax errors,) Why would this work if adding the `active` class with those same colour properties didn't?

Comment: This would not work,  think because when the links load

Comment: Doesn't this break all the link navigation? (The OP's original code works if you disable all the page navigation.)

Comment: @nnnnnn could you explain what is the question ?

Comment: Here @ihemant360 the links don't load. I would want if a link loads to remain the that purple color until the user leaves the page or clicks another page.

Comment: replace # with your link.

Comment: Finally You got it , Good luck with your Project

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply this?

```
.navigation-menu li a:active {
    background-color: purple;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Instead of trying to modify CSS classes with JQuery, why not simply do it all with CSS.

CSS active state is defined as

```
:active
```

Not as

```
.active
```

(Just in case you were trying to target the state and not intentionally doing it using classes)

Edit:

```
$(".navigation.menu").click(function(){
    $(".navigation.menu").css("color","#fff");
    $this.css("color","#f0f");
});
```

This may work for you, apologies if this edit is not completely correct as I am on my phone.

Comment: Hello @Aidan I want when a link is active it to remain in that purple color until another is clicked.

Comment: Apparently, doesn't work. Only changes when being clicked not when active

Answer (score 0):

When a link is clicked your click handler will run to change the class (and thus colour) of the clicked item *in the current page*, but then the normal page navigation will occur and the specified page will load, overwriting the change that was applied to the previous page.

Rather than using a click handler, you could run some code when the page loads to extract the page name from `location.href` and then use it as a selector to set the class on the anchor corresponding to the current page.

That is, if you could somehow tell that the current page is `bsms.php` then you could say `$("a['href=bsms.php']).addClass("active");`. So how would you do that? Here's one way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentPage = location.href.match(/\/(\w+\.php)/);
  if (currentPage) {
    $("a[href='" + currentPage[1] + "']").addClass("active");
  }
});
```

This uses a regex that assumes the structure of your URLs is some variation on the following:

```
www.somedomainname.com/optional/folders/pagename.php?optionalargs=something
```

and just gets the `pagename.php` part.

The regular expression matches as follows:

```
\/         - a forward slash (which has to be escaped in the regex)
(          - beginning of a sub match
\w+        - one or more "word" characters
\.         - a literal .
php        - the literal characters php
)          - end of the sub match
```

The `currentPage` variable will be `null` if there was no match, otherwise it will be an array where the element at index 1 is the page name.