# How can I style links I loaded from a txt file with the jQuery load() method into my HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to load some links from a text file into a navigation menu using the jQuery AJAX load() method. It's working fine when it loads the links but it won't let me apply an active class for the current link. It applies all the other CSS for the links but not the active class. Am I missing anything?

My HTML/jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#cat-1-button').click(function(){
                $('#sec-nav-container').show();
                $('#sec-nav-items').load('textfile.txt #cat-1-items');
                return false;
            });

            $('.subCat').click(function() {
                $('.subCat').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                return false;
            });

        });

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="sec-nav-container> 
            <div id="sec-nav-items> </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" id="cat-1-button"> Click Here </button>

    </body>

</html>
```

Textfile:

```
<div id="cat-1-items">
        <a href="#" class="subCat"> cat1-sub1 </a>
        <a href="#" class="subCat"> cat1-sub2 </a>
        <a href="#" class="subCat"> cat1-sub3 </a>
        <a href="#" class="subCat"> cat1-sub4 </a>
        <a href="#" class="subCat"> cat1-sub5 </a>
        <a href="#" class="subCat"> cat1-sub6 </a>
        <a href="#" class="subCat"> cat1-sub7 </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #6b00b3;
}
```

Comment: why this two events for one target ` $('.subCat').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');`

Comment: I put it the remove one there so when I click another link it removes the class from any links who already had it that way there is only one link with the .active class.

Comment: i think your answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045413/active-link-turn-different-color/38045554#38045554  it's different but some how related ....

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add rule for pseudo-element `:visited`

```
.active,.active:visited {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #6b00b3;
}
```

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/qaepsamr/1)

__

Check also your html , for example, you have here some issues :

- `<div id="sec-nav-container">` instead of `<div id="sec-nav-container>`
- `<div id="sec-nav-items">` instead of `<div id="sec-nav-items>`

Answer (score 0):

try this replace instead  $('.subCat').click(function()...

```
$('#sec-nav-items').on( 'click', 'a.subCat', function(){
  $('.subCat').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  return false;
})
```

Comment: Can you please accept this answer for another persons helpful this answer.